# How to replace middle picture window

Tags: installation

I'm trying to remove and replace a middle picture window that is attached to two crank windows.  I can't figure out what is holding the picture window in place, if it is screws, where are they coming from? would I have to remove drywall to see them? the new windows is a replacement from the same company as the original window, so I think it is identical to the existing window.  I see these grey plastic things screwed into both windows, but I'm not sure if they are spacers or what is holding the window in place.  I've attached a gallary of images of the existing and new window.

https://postimg.cc/gallery/g8dPBVY

[image]

Comment: There are usually holes for mounting the windows and are visible when the windows are opened up. they could also be between the glass and the screen. Could be caulked over or a plastic cover.

Comment: The only hole a screw could possibly be placed in the new window  would require it being set from inside the drywall

Comment: In most caes a 3-part window like that is one unit when installed (all 3 stuck together at the factory, and they go into a single opening in the framing - not 3 separate bits into 3 separate holes.) If you have a manufacturer's replacement due to a problem with the center window, ask the manufacturer for advice on how to get it out and in, as assembled.

Comment: @Ecnerwal that sounds like the most likely answer to the question. That'd get my upvote...

Answer (score 1):

Often the insulated glass unit ("IGU") is a component separate from the vinyl window frame and can be replaced without need to remove the entire window frame. There may be a removable "stop" as shown in the photo below from [Family Handyman](https://www.familyhandyman.com/project/how-to-replace-insulating-glass/). If so then one would remove that stop, then cut the foam mounting tape on the oppose side of the glass using a thin putty knife, then remove the IGU from the frame. Installation is the reverse.

[image: window stop removal]

One could buy the bare IGU made to order in just the right size to fit the existing frame. Since you already have a complete new window with frame, hopefully its IGU is the same size as the one in your existing frame so that the IGUs can be swapped and the new frame discarded.

Answer (score 0):

New construction windows typically have a nailing fin which is attached to the external sheathing. This flange is hidden under your siding and molding.

[image]

What you received seems to be a pocket replacement window.

If my assessment is wrong then ask the manufacturer for further assistance; hopefully, they can direct you to a YouTube video.

Comment: you are right about there not being any flanges. I didn’t know the term pocket window so that is helpful to describe to people, thanks! I’ll try giving the manufacturer a call

Comment: I would consider hiring a pro.